# Media query não funciona em site não responsivo

Tags: css3, media-queries

Boa tarde a todos, eu coloquei media query css3 para funcionar em um site com largura fixa, mas não funciona. Só funciona em sites responsivos?

http://bblender.com.br/clientes/moldin/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
.tit-h2{margin-left:2px!important;}
#rodape{
width: 104%;
height: 180px;
background: #F68624;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;}}
```

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 3):

Você deve colocar a `METATAG VIEWPORT` no cabeçalho `HEAD` da página:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

OBS: Você pode modifica-lá a sua necessidade alterando o valor dos atributos:

- **width** - Define uma largura para o viewport. Os valores podem ser em
  PX ou “device-width”, que determina automaticamente um valor igual a
  largura da tela do dispositivo.
- **height** - Define uma altura para o viewport. Os valores podem ser em
  PX ou “device-height”, que determina automaticamente um valor igual a
  altura da tela do dispositivo.
- **initial-scale** - Define a escala inicial do viewport.
- **user-scalable** - Define a possibilidade de o usuário fazer “zoom” em
  um determinado lugar da tela. É ativado quando o usuário bate duas
  vezes com o dedo em um lugar da tela.

Com CSS você só define os estilos para cada resolução.

A `METATAG` é para informar o dispositivo que a largura que ele deve usar é a largura que aparenta ter, e não a da resolução dele que é em `PIXELS`.

Você precisa utilizar CSS com `MEDIA QUERIES` e a `METATAG VIEWPORT`.

Recomendo que você comece a trabalhar com medidas relativas ao invés de fixas para trabalhar com layouts responsivos pois são mais adequadas.

Comment: resolvi, esta assim agora.

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 959px) {
    .tit-h2{margin-left:2px!important;}
    #rodape{
    width: 104%;
    height: 180px;
    background: #F68624;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
}

Comment: Se utilizar assim (max-device-width: 959px), ele vai funcionar somente em devices. O monitor é um desktop, não um dispositivo mobile. Se você colocar só o min-width, max-width, ele irá atender a qualquer tipo de tela, não apenas a mobiles e por isso deve-se utilizar a metatag viewport.

Comment: Vlw pela dica, mas foi mesmo só neste caso especial que precisava  ajeitar este detalhe do titulo.