# Problema na versão responsiva do site

Tags: wordpress, layout-responsivo

Boa tarde pessoal,

Desenvolvi um site para um cliente, em wordpress, o site é sgcsolucoes.com.br. O meu problema é que parece que o css responsivo não está pegando. O site para desktop está certinho. Quando abro no celular, abre a mesma versão do desktop, mas quando vou no menu personalizar e escolho o modo responsivo, no simulador fica certinho, mas quando abro no celular continua aparecendo a versão para desktop.

Já desativei todos os plugins, já escolhi outro tema e, mesmo assim não funciona.

O Site responsivo, deveria ficar como na imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado!

Comment: É o seu Cash do navegador Aqui abriu normal responsivo olha ai: http://prntscr.com/lt790y

Comment: O site responsivo deveria ficar como na imagem.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada é no seu CSS que não está funcionando a questão do menu.

Answer (score 2):

Seu problema é que talvez por algum motivo vc removeu essa linha do seu `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Aqui tem mais detalhes sobre o que é e os valores dessa `meta tag` [Media query não funciona em site não responsivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51244/media-query-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-site-n%C3%A3o-responsivo/51248#51248)

**Veja na imagem, quado eu insiro essa linha no seu `head` o estilo responsivo passa a ser aplicado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa meta tag está incluída na função business_point_head, do arquivo hooks.php. Tentei incluir manualmente, mas não funcionou

Comment: @DanielBrito eu não sei como é o seu tema, cada um pode ser de um jeito, mas aqui seria assim... http://prntscr.com/lt832p vc tem que ver como é no seu.

Comment: Abri o arquivo header.php e adicionei essa tag......quando eu redimeciono a janela do navegador, o layout responsivo funciona, mas quando abro no celular, não pega o layout responsivo.

Comment: @DanielBrito agora deve ser o cash do browser mesmo... Tenta limpar ai. Ou então eh Pq se cel tem a resolução muito alta, maior que seu media query

Comment: Acredito que não, porque se eu apertar F12 no chrome, e selecionar a versão mobile, também não pega o layout responsivo. Quando vou na guia elements, a meta tag não está lá também.

Comment: @DanielBrito desculpe não poder te ajudar mais... o problema acredito ser essa meta tag ai mesmo, agora a forma como vc vai coloca-la no head que vai ser o problema...